# Bayesian updating on binomial process

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, statistics, combinations

I'm running a simulation in which agents update beliefs based on the results of a binomial(n, p) process. That part goes something like

```
from numpy.random import binomial, random
from scipy.misc import comb
import math

eps = 0.01
belief = random()
n = 1100
result = binomial(n, 0.5 + eps)

prob2 = comb(n, result)*math.pow(0.5 + eps, result)*math.pow(.5 - eps, n - result)
prob1 = comb(n, result)*math.pow(0.5 - eps, result)*math.pow(.5 + eps, n - result)
bottom = prob2*belief + prob1*(1 - belief)
top = prob2*belief

bayes = top/bottom
```

The problem is, if n is greater than about 1000, the result of comb(n, result) is "inf", so the rest of the calculation stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mathematically simplify the likelihood ratio expression, you'll find that `comb(n, result)` cancels out. You don't need to include it at all.